# is there any way to add integers from an array without take elements to outside

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray

an array contain integer values.is there any way to add the integer values without take it out side.

```
       NSMutableArray *total_point = @[@1, @2, @3, @4, @5, @6];
 for (int i = 0; i < total_point.count; i++) {
            int res1;
            res1 = [(NSNumber *)[total_point objectAtIndex:i] intValue];

        }
```

how to add elements from inside the array